# Formatting string to numbers to comma-separated values using JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jsf page, I have an inputtext with a string value. The input should be numbers only but I want it to automatically be formatted after I enter the data. For example:

I inputted 1000, after entering the data it will be formatted to 1,000

My input text looks like so:

```
<h:inputText value="#{Bean.myInputText}" styleClass="strFormatter">
   <p:ajax event="blur" update="@this"/>
</h:inputText>
```

My script looks like so:

```
$(".strFormatter").blur (
   function() {
    var strToFormat = $(this).val();
    return strToFormat.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?1\d))g, "$1,");
})
```

But this does not work so my question is, how can I format my string of numbers automatically to be comma-separated after input without triggering any actions?

Comment: instead of `return strToFormat.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?1\d))g, "$1,");`  use `$(this).val(strToFormat.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?1\d))g, "$1,"))`

Comment: thanks but the same thing happens.

Comment: check you regex, I haven't looked at that... any error in your browser console

Answer (score 2):

Try this example:

```
var n = 1000;
console.log(n.toLocaleString()); //<-- prints: "1,000"

n = 234234;
console.log(n.toLocaleString()); //<-- prints: "234,234"
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this also and it didn't work either

Comment: @user1597438, which browser are you using, encountered errors, if any ?

Comment: IE. there were no errors. it just didn't work some reason.

Comment: @user1597438, IE which version ? I have tested it in IE 8 as well, works for me ! Please check directly once into the IE console

Comment: @user1597438, please check I have uploaded my IE console output